# What do the [..] mean in 'ps' and how do you create a process like it?

Tags: linux, daemon

When running `ps`, you get something like:

```
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   00:00   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   00:00   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   00:00   0:00 [events/0]
```

All the daemon processes generally have the `[..]` brackets around them.

What do they mean (if anything)?
How do you create a process that appears like this?

The reason I ask is we create a system daemon from the rcS (the programme uses fork to create the daemon), but ps entry looks like:

```
root       207  0.0  0.2   1516   200 ?        S    00:00   0:00 /root/testdaemo
```

So we were wondering if it is important to have the `[..]` brackets and how processes get them in the first place.

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22121/what-do-the-brackets-around-processes-mean

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Square brackets are used for processes that do not have an associated command line (mostly kernel threads and some system services).

If I recall correctly, you might be able to achieve the same effect for your process by setting `argv[0]` to the empty string.

Comment: `mostly` - what can make an exception?

Comment: What does the trailing /0 mean?

Comment: @RyanN, it means that kernel thread is running on the first CPU.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are kernel threads, created by kernel subsystems. They are created using kthread_create() or kernel_thread() functions in kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't even show the `[...]`, so I'm not 100% sure what you're talking about. However it IS possible to modify the `argv` arguments of any program (in Linux). The arguments are reflected in the output of `ps`.

Comment: `[...]` was meant as a placeholder. I was referring to the `[kthreadd]` <- the `[]` that encapsulate the name.

Comment: ah I see. Then yes I believe those are kernel processes.